# How to edit Datagrid view in other form

Tags: datagridview

```
form.Labelname.Text = MyDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
form.TextBox1.Text = MyDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
```

This code only show the data what code I'm going to use to edit the data grid view in other form.

Comment: Bind the control to a datasource that is available to both forms. Then modify the datasource. That's the basics of my suggestion anyway.

Comment: Can you clarify what language you are using?